# Do I get a free checked-in luggage item on this flight?

Tags: luggage, code-share, vueling

Iberia 5981 Operated by VUELING AIRLINES

[Iberia policy](http://www.iberia.com/gb/luggage/allowance-in-hold/) includes free checked-in luggage of 23 kg, while [Vueling policy](http://www.vueling.com/en/vueling-services/prepare-your-trip/luggage) doesn't include free check-in luggage.

Do I get a free checked-in luggage item on this flight?

Comment: What is you class of travel? Basic or Classic Flexible? Iberia does not allow free luggage on domestic or EU flights except for business and Classic flexible classes.

Comment: I was suspecting that I have to pay 15 or 30 EUR even on Iberia for checked-in luggage because my class doesn't have free allowance. http://www.iberia.com/gb/baggage/additional-baggage/ But then I clicked on *Manage my booking* and it said 1 piece free, for both legs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always follow the *marketing* airline's policy, in other words, the airline that sold you the ticket, regardless of which airline is *operating* the flight. In your case that's Iberia.

Comment: Sorry, but as a general answer ('always') this is COMPLETELY WRONG.  For some airlines it's the marketing carrier, for others it's the operating carrier.